# create-react-app, react-slick, video playback holds while sound is playing

Tags: reactjs, video, html5-video, create-react-app, react-slick

I'm implementing kiosk program using react.
There is a problem which is really weird.

The first screen shows slides using react-slick.

Slides include pictures and videos.

Sometimes, video stops playing while only the sound of the video is playing.

I checked event from video element. While the video stops, 'play' event is triggered.

In order to play sound, you need to change settings in chrome.

Input chrome://settings/content/sound in chrome address, and add a site 'localhost' to 'allowed sites to play sound'.
This problem reproduces randomly.

You can test with 'npm start' command.

Here's github source code link.
[source](https://github.com/eunwoo/kiosk)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.
I changed slide library from react-slick to swiper-react.
I don't know exactly why the problem was solved.
You can see the source code in my github.